# Undefined symbol when loading Augeas bindings in Lua

Tags: binding, lua, augeas

I'm trying to load the Lua Augeas bindings using the Lua 5.1 standalone interpreter:

```
$ lua5.1 
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> require 'augeas'
error loading module 'augeas' from file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/augeas.so':
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/augeas.so: undefined symbol: aug_close
stack traceback:
    [C]: ?
    [C]: in function 'require'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
>
$ nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/augeas.so | grep close
             U aug_close
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `lua-augeas` library in Ubuntu is an old version which was not built with the necessary flags to make link it to the Augeas library.